# MySQL - How to change the primary key while importing the data from one database to another database?

Tags: mysql

Basically, I have two table users and user_details. Users table is as follows.

```
id  name
1   A
2   B
```

and user details table is as follows

```
id  user_id division    branch
1   1         D1        B1
2   1         D2        B2
```

User_details table have user_id as the foreign key.

I need to import data from these two table into another database having similar two tables.

The problem is tables in db2 might already have entries with similar primary keys of user table. i.e. same user_id's.

Is there any way , I can change primary keys while maintaining the foreign key relation with user details table.

e.g. If db2 has user ids till 100, user id from db 1 should become 101 and this should also change the corresponding user id in user details table to 101 and so on.

Comment: Assuming that `db2` only has 100 users, then adding 100 to the user id might work as you migrate the data.

Comment: ohh that simple !!!

Comment: There is probably a textbook way of doing this, but that it just a suggestion.  You also need to make sure that the auto increment of the `users.id` column isn't affected by this.